# How to use dropdown using bootstrap 4 in Angular?

Tags: angular, styling

I'm trying to add a bootstrap 4 dropdown in my Angular application but when I click on the dropdown it doesn't do anything. I'm not using any bootstrap.js or jquery.js in node modules.

Answer (score 2):

Had similar issue with Bootsrap Modal Component. Found out that the `ng-bootstrap` was missing and different from the my bootsrap I had. Try to install it:

1. intsall: `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`
2. add `import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'` to `app.module.ts` file.
3. add `NgbModule` inside `imports: []` in the same file.

Example source file looks like this:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // for input data

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TaskViewComponent,
    TaskCardComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```